# RestEntity mapping returns null object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have got endpoint which returns json:

```
{
  "scan_configurations": [
    {
      "id": "0e2d28dc-d26d-4c43-a28a-8e6c65c28345",
      "name": "Audit checks - all except JavaScript analysis",
      "burp_config_fragment": "{}",
      "built_in": true,
      "last_modified_time": "2020-03-30T09:17:16.763Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "6da6a5d8-d50f-436e-a99f-54ed258ab3a6",
      "name": "Audit checks - all except time-based detection methods",
      "burp_config_fragment": "{}",
      "built_in": true,
      "last_modified_time": "2020-03-30T09:17:16.774Z"
    }]
}
```

And my structured object:

```
public class ScanConfiguration implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("scan_configurations")
    List<Configuration> configurationList;

    public List<Configuration> getConfigurationList() {
        return configurationList;
    }

    public void setConfigurationList(List<Configuration> configurationList) {
        this.configurationList = configurationList;
    }
}
public class Configuration {
    String id;
    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
 ResponseEntity<ScanConfiguration> response = restTemplate.exchange(scanner.getApiUrl() + "/api-internal/scan-configurations",
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, ScanConfiguration.class);
```

I get `response.statusCode = 200` but `response.body.getConfigurationList()` is null. could anyone give me a hint what is wrong with my Objects so they cannot be mapped?

resonse.toString():

```
<200,io.apiclient.integrations.webappscan.plugin.burpee.model.ScanConfiguration@49f583aa,[Date:"Wed, 01 Apr 2020 19:11:51 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Content-Security-Policy:"base-uri 'none'; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self' blob:; style-src 'self' 'sha256-deDIoPlRijnpfbTDYsK+8JmDfUBmpwpnb0L/SUV8NeU='; frame-src 'self'; form-action 'none'; connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:3333; font-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; child-src 'self' blob:", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", Referrer-Policy:"strict-origin-when-cross-origin", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", Vary:"Accept-Encoding, User-Agent", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"]>
```

Comment: Not that solid with Spring but shouldn't `Confiuration` define all parameters?

Comment: can you debug or log what `response.toString()` is returning?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch edited qustion

Comment: I thought that the content of the `ScanConfiguration` class would be printed as well. Can you add a `toString()` method to your class that shows the content?

Comment: but there is none. While debugging i am getting `ScanConfiguration .configurationList = null` and can't figure out how this object should look like to it could be mapped by provided json

Comment: @P.J.Meisch fun fact. When I remove `@JsonProperty` annotation and rename variable to  "scan_configurations" object is being properly mapped

Comment: because then your java property name is the same as the json field. So it seems that Jackson does not pick up the annotation.